# Get results of an array returned from API

Tags: php, arrays

I have data getting from from an API. The result is an array that looks like :

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "value": 1.50590809747133,
      "timestamp": 1558540800
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1558548000,
      "value": 1.52303142144612
    },
    {
      "value": 1.49521152223328,
      "timestamp": 1558555200
    }
  ],
  "unit": "%"
}
```

How should I do to build another array composed of all the "value" items only(1.50, 1.52, 1.49)?

Any help would be very appreciated
Thanks !

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and where it is going wrong.

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know to decode the JSON.  Then just extract the column that you want, in this case `value`:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$result = array_column($array['values'], 'value');
```

Answer (score -1):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
$associative_array = json_decode($json, true);
$indexed_array = array_values($associative_array);
```

There you go.